# Set lz4 topic compression for materialized state stores

Tags: quarkus, apache-kafka-streams

Assume a Quarkus Kafka Streams application doing some kind of re-keying and aggregation with materialization like this:

```java
final KTable<Long, GroupedCommunications> groupedCommunications = communications //
        .groupBy( //
                (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value.personId(), value), //
                Grouped.with( //
                        "communications-grouped", //
                        longKeySerde, //
                        communicationSerde)) //
        .aggregate( //
                GroupedCommunications::new, //
                (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.add(value), //
                (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.remove(value), //
                Named.as("communications-grouped-aggregated"), //
                Materialized //
                        .<Long, GroupedCommunications, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("communications-grouped-aggregated-materialized") //
                        .withKeySerde(longKeySerde) //
                        .withValueSerde(groupedCommunicationSerde));
```

This implicitly creates two Kafka topics `communications-grouped-repartition` and `communications-grouped-aggregated-materialized-changelog` with compression type `producer`.

How do I change this to `lz4`? Setting `kafka-streams.producer.compression-type=lz4` has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do mean by "has no effect"? Is the data not written using lz4 by the producer? Or are you only asking about the topic config itself?

Compression can be configured at a topic level config and as a producer level config, and both configs "interact". In the end, topic config for compression type set to "producer" tells the broker to write the data into the topic just accepting the format the producer picked -- if the producer is configured with lz4, data would be written in lz4.

If you change the topic level compression config, the broker might need to re-compress the data to match the required format in case that the producer is configured with a different compression format, thus, keeping compression format at "producer" is usually the best thing to avoid re-compression overhead. For example, if the producer compression is turned-off, the broker would compress using lz4 before writing the data -- if producer compression is set to snappy, the broker would first decompress the data, and afterward recompress into lz4 before writing the data.

Using the `producer.` prefix does change the producer config only (not the topic config), ie, how does the producer compress the data and send to the broker. Are you saying the producer is not use lz4 as configured?

If you really want to, you can add topic specific configuration for internal topic to your Kafka Streams configuration using config name prefix `topic.`, eg, `topic.compression-type=lz4`. This would change the topic level config, however, if the producer is not configured with compression (by default it's "none" IIRC), compression would now only happen broker side as explained above, most likely not what you want.

Comment: Hm, then actually I guess I can't tell which compression type is used. Setting the above mentioned configuration `kafka-streams.producer.compression.type=lz4` leads to the broker (correctly) stating the compression type as 'producer', but I can't tell which that is... How can I assure the producer compresses the messages correctly in order to lower (topic) disk pressure on the broker side?

Comment: Well, you would need to monitor the producer application directly. If you want to _enforce_ the compression type broker side, you can still set the topic level config to "lz4" (instead of "producer"). For this case, as long as the producer complies, there won't be overhead (AFAIK), but of course, if the producer does not comply, the broker would just re-compress... Also cf https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-message-compression/ (might be helpful).

Comment: It's possible to verify with low level tools... `kafka-run-class.bat kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments` will show the used on-disk compression.